# How to compile the JDK from sources?

Tags: java, compilation

Is there a way to compile the JDK from sources?
And is there an official download of the source?
I want to compile it for my Smartphone.

Comment: The jdk already has the source code inside of it, no need to download separately.

Comment: Yes. But I want to know how to compile it.

Comment: The same way as any other Java code.

Comment: Yes but Java can't be only java code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is completely valid. JDK has multiple repositories (forest), code form only JDK repository will not work to build complete JDK. Also, it's very hard to get a source of an older version.

Please refer to the following document to build OpenJDK.

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk9u/raw-file/tip/common/doc/building.html

Following is main steps to build code:

1. Download the code from the root repository. Please check [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u) link for all available repository tree.
2. Run the get_source.sh script located in the root repository to get
   the other needed repositories
3. Then follow step provided in README file in the root repository

Also if anyone wants to have prebuilt binary then it available via adoptjdk project at the following URL.

https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html

Updates: 5 Feb, 2021

As part of [Project Skara](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/skara/), openJDK source code is moved from Mercurial to Git. Please refer following new guideline to build JDK11+.

https://openjdk.java.net/groups/build/doc/building.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24813436)

Comment: Edited my answer and included essential steps to move forward in build.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK is already the compiled source and has all the source files inside of it. Some are only class files but most of java is open source.

However, you can check out openJDK.

http://openjdk.java.net/

Thats basically the version of java you want to get hacky with.