# Is there a JDK for Mac OS that you can debug with LLDB?

Tags: java, macos, lldb

I am currently trying to debug a problem in a Java program that at some point jumps into a JNI function and never returns from it. So to debug this JNI code I want to attach LLDB. The problem is that the Java process does not have the `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` entitlement set, so the debugger cannot attach to the process.

Apparently one possible solution is to disable system integrity protection at boot time. As I am working on a company machine this is sadly not possible for me.

Is there a JDK version that has the required entitlement set?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2147/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003827-CH1-DEBUG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any pre-compiled JDK binaries with `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` set, but if you are willing to compile the binary from source there is a configuration option to set the entitlement: `--with-macosx-codesign=debug` which will attempt to perform adhoc signing to add the special entitlement `com.apple.security.get-task-allow`

You can read how to compile your own JDK from:

Here: [How to compile the JDK from sources? at stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343723/how-to-compile-the-jdk-from-sources)

and Here [Building the JDK. at openjdk.org](https://openjdk.org/groups/build/doc/building.html)

if you are willing to download a bunch of JDKs, you can use `codesign -d --entitlements :- /path/to/jdk/bin/java` to check for the `get-task-allow` entitlement or `codesign -dv --verbose=4 /path/to/jdk/bin/java` to see if `Signature=adhoc` is set